GameKit: Why does the local player have a display name of "Anonymous"?
I am retrieving leaderboard data for an iOS app, using GameKit. More specifically I use this GameKit method (link to documentation):
func loadEntries(
    for playerScope: GKLeaderboard.PlayerScope,
    timeScope: GKLeaderboard.TimeScope,
    range: NSRange,
    completionHandler: @escaping (GKLeaderboard.Entry?, [GKLeaderboard.Entry]?, Int, (any Error)?) -> Void
)

The first value in the result that the method returns is supposed to be the local player entry. Now I encountered a weird issue: When I set the PlayerScope to .friendsOnly, everything works fine. But when I set the PlayerScope to .global, the local player object behaves weirdly: When I try to access its 'displayName' property I do not get the actual display name back but the string "Anonymous". Same happens for the player photo.
Does anyone have an idea what is happening here?

The local player entry returned by this call may be anonymous if it is outside the range of the fetched entries. When the scope is .friendsOnly, it is more likely that the local player entry is included in the fetched entries (unless the player has a lot of friends).
The documentation that you referenced describes the parameter as follows:

localPlayerEntry
The score for the local player, or nil if the player has no score.

If the entry is present then the score will be valid, but there is no mention of other information being provided (although to be fair, there is no mention that it is not provided either). But the entry may be nil if the player has no score.
In general, if you need static information about the local player, like the display name, then there is no need to rely on the entry delivered here. Just get the information from GKLocalPlayer.local.

Thanks for the comment. I agree with your take. What was making me wonder was that only name and player photo seem to be unavailable if the local player is out of range, while the score and rank of the local player are being returned even if the local player is not i.g. in the top 100.
